# Open form as a pop up VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm opening a pop up window using this code.

```
Public Sub ChkAvl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChkAvl.Click

    Dim query As String = "PreOrderItemAvailability.aspx"
    Dim myWin As String = "window.open('" & query & "');"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "pop", myWin, True)

End Sub


 <dx:ASPxButton ID="ChkAvl" runat="server" Text="Check Item Availability" BackColor="#D0E4FE" Cursor="pointer" EnableDefaultAppearance="False" Font-Names="Roboto" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#2C4D79" CssClass="AdminPageBtn"   OnClick="ChkAvl_Click" >
                                 <Border BorderColor="#A3C0E8" BorderWidth="1px"  />
                           </dx:ASPxButton>
```

But when executing this nothing happen.PreOrderItemAvailability.aspx not opening.
why is that?

Comment: The line seems to be correct. Are you sure that _PreOrderItemAvailability.aspx_ is in the same folder of the calling page?

Comment: yes.those are in same folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a form like a pop up then simply try like this:

VB.NET

```
Dim query As String = "PreOrderItemAvailability.aspx" 
Dim myWin As String = "window.open('" & query & "');"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "pop", myWin, True)
```

In ASP.NET:

```
string query = "PreOrderItemAvailability.aspx" ;
string myWin ="window.open('" + query + "');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", myWin, true);
```

Comment: @Heinzi:- I went with the title tag! :)

Comment: How to give the aspx page name?

Comment: When executing your code nothing happen. popup not opening. No errors.

Comment: @Tom:- Nothing is wrong in this code. you need to add more details as to how you are calling it and from where?